# Transition not working on text

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've added code to enlarge the text when it is moused over but it is not working. Can anyone see the reason why? Here is my [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/tvxz0m2w/) I don't think it matters but the font being used in the actual code is being loaded through font-face but I thought i should mention it.

```
    <style>
    .headerText {transition: all .2s ease-in-out;}
    .headerText:hover {transform: scale(2.1);}
    a.headerText {
       font-family: arial;
       font-weight:bold;
       font-style:none;
       font-size:28px; 
       text-decoration:none;
       text-align:center;  
       color:purple;
       white-space:nowrap;  
       margin-left:20px;
       line-height:1.6;   
    }
    a.headerText:hover {color:green;}
    </style>

    <span class="headerText"><a class="headerText" href="http://example.com">my link</a></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Transform property doesn't apply on inline elements**, and `<span>` is one of them.

[Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element) you can see list of elements that can be transformed.

> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS2]
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, patternTransform or gradientTransform [SVG11].

#### Solution

Set the `display` property of the span to `inline-block` or `block`.

```css
.headerText {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.headerText:hover {
  transform: scale(2.1);
}

a.headerText {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: purple;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

a.headerText:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="headerText">
  <a class="headerText" href="http://example.com">
    my link
  </a>
</span>
```